# doxygen warning for not existing group?

Tags: doxygen

Say I write

```
\ingroup mygroup
```

for a piece of code but `mygroup` was not not defined as

```
\defgroup mygroup
```

or was create as say `myGroup` (typo for instance) then this will not result in a warning, but the code is simply not assigned to the module.

Is there an option that triggers a warning in such a case?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? The problem might be a candidate for an enhancement request (in the doxygen issue tracker on GitHub).

Comment: @albert Doxgen 1.9.5

Comment: Current doxygen version is 1.9.8, but that makes no difference regarding the warning request.

Comment: Despite a missing issue I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 10289, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/10289)

Comment: Code has been integrated in master on GitHub.